# Can I use my extended hard drive partition for Windows OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

**Background**

About a year ago I bought a desktop computer with Windows 7 pre-installed. Shortly after I burned the Ubuntu16.04 OS on a flash drive, and partitioned my hard drive to give Ubuntu almost the entire size, but still dual boot with Windows. I'm now wanting to re-partition my hard drive so my Windows 7 partition and Ubuntu partition are equal in size.

**Hard Drive**

I have included a picture of my hard drive partitions here.

[image]

1) System Re Partition 1

**size**:  105MB

**device**: /dev/sda1

**Partition Type**: HPFS/NTFS (Bootable)

**Contents**: NTFS-Not Mounted

2) Filesystem Partition 2

**size**:  49GB

**device**: /dev/sda2

**Partition Type**: HPFS/NTFS

**Contents**: NTFS-Not Mounted

3) Extended Partition 3

**size**:  431GB

**device**: /dev/sda3

**Partition Type**: Extended

**Contents**: Extended Partition

4) Filesystem Partition 5

**size**:  414GB - 366 GB free (11.7% full)

**device**: /dev/sda5

**Partition Type**: Linux

**Contents**: Ext4(version1.0) - Moounted at Filesystem Root

5) Swap Partition 6

**size**:  17 GB

**device**: /dev/sda6

**Partition Type**: Linux Swap

**Contents**: Swap (version 1) - Active

**Question**

1) Assuming my windows OS is on Partition 2, should I take memory from Partition 5?

2) What is the Extended Partition used for? It appears to just be the sum of Partition 5 (Ubuntu) and 6 (Swap)

**UPDATE**
On boot, I've noticed that my windows OS is on /dev/sda1 (System Repartition 1) NOT /dev/sda2 (Filesystem Partition 2). So what is the purpose of /dev/sda2?

Thanks again for your help.

[on_boot_options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6KtL.jpg)

Comment: MBR drive can only have 4 primary partitions. Extended partition is used to create logical drives. I believe windows must be installed to a primary partition; however, ubuntu can be installed on a logical drive

Comment: sda2 is your primary Windows partition.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. On startup, I do not have the choice to access sda2. How do you know its the primary Windows partition? Can you provide more details as I'm not very fluent in partitions.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use your extended partition for Windows, it is formated in Ext4 format, which windows do not understand!
1. You cannot take space from an extended partition, you have to take it from partition 3 (see Ravery's comment)
2.  The extended partition are for holding all partitions above AND including partition 4 (GPT do not have this limitation, that is mainly why we are all changing to GPT)
The old MBR way of doing things date back to the old days when a partition could max be 32 MB (that's right megabyte your USB-sticks are way bigger now)

You can create an NTFS partition for say Pictures and videos, and mount it in both Ubuntu and Windows!

This way you can edit and watch your files from both OS'es, and use the apps you are most familiar with - therby get the most satisfying experience out of both OS'es!

Comment: There is a ext driver for windows that can handle ext4. example http://www.ext2fsd.com/ or https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to approach this...

**The safest way would be to:**

- backup your important Ubuntu and Windows documents
- remove Ubuntu (sda3/5/6) note: you won't be able to boot Windows now
- use a `Windows Repair` disc, or `boot-repair`, to fix the no-Windows boot problem
- extend the Windows partition using Windows own Disk Management tool
- reinstall Ubuntu

**The more risky way would be to:**

- backup your important Ubuntu documents
- boot a `Ubuntu Live` DVD/USB
- resize sda5 and move it right using `gparted`
- resize sda3 using `gparted`
- boot into Windows
- extend the Windows partition using Windows own Disk Management tool

**Update #1:**

`gparted` move/resize notes...

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it still safe/possible to re-partition my Windows (partition 1) without the Windows Repair disc. I do not have one.

Comment: Then use method #2. Make sure you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.